# Creating an executable from a java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have three classes, one of them is called `Main` and contains a `main` method, and no package. The IDE I use is *eclipse*. If I click `File > Export` and then select `Java > Runable JAR File` I'd expect to get a file that I can double-click and that'll run my program. However, that's not the case. If I click the resulting file nothing happens. I'm very new to this whole thing, so my questions are: Is this file even supposed to be clickable, or am I missing a step to run it? If that's the case, how to I convert the file to a `.exe` file (I really don't get this manifest-stuff, so please explain in detail how that needs to be done)? Basically: How do I create an executable (executable as in "works if i just click on it") file from three classes (with *eclipse* if possible)?

Edit: It's a console app.

Comment: have you created a console application or gui one?

Comment: oh ur right that would be nice to know... its a console app

Comment: so you have to run it through cmd you can not do it directly

Comment: Console apps just run in the background. This is how those work (at least with javaw)